# Problemas con try / except en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo lo básico de Python 3 y me encuentro con los ejercicios de principiante que hay en la web.
Tengo problemas con el try / except. El try funciona sin problemas pero cuando quiero dar un msj de error el except parece que no lo reconoce. Me da un error de traceback.
Quiero que cuando se ponga algo que no sea un numero me de ese error, pero no se que pasa..
Si coloco números funciona bien.

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bienvenida.
Gracias

```
hr = input('Horas de trabajo: ')
phr = input('Precio por hr de trabajo: ')
    try
        fh=float(hr)
        fhr=float(phr)
    except:
        print('Error, entre un numero valido')
        quit()
    
    if hr>40:
        exfh = (fh - 40) * (fhr*0.5)
        prtot = (fh) * (fhr)
        tot= exfh + prtot
    else:
        tot = (fh) * (fhr)
    print(fh, fhr)
    print('Pay: ', tot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no está en como usas el try/except. Tienes varios errores en el código:

### Problemas de indentación

Tienes:

```
...
phr = input('Precio por hr de trabajo: ')
    try
        fh=float(hr)
        fhr=float(phr)
    except:
        ...
```

y deberías tenerlo así:

```
...
phr = input('Precio por hr de trabajo: ')
try
    fh=float(hr)
    fhr=float(phr)
except:
    ...
```

### Otros errores

- A tu `try` le faltan los dos puntos, debería ser así `try:`
- Conviertes la stringa `hr` en número y lo guardas en la variable `fh` para luego no utilizarla en el condicional al decir `if hr>40:` donde hr sigue siendo una stringa y deberías haber usado `fh`.

### Código corregido

```
hr = input('Horas de trabajo: ')
phr = input('Precio por hr de trabajo: ')
try:
    fh=float(hr)
    fhr=float(phr)
except:
    print('Error, entre un numero valido')
    quit()

if fh>40:
    exfh = (fh - 40) * (fhr*0.5)
    prtot = (fh) * (fhr)
    tot = exfh + prtot
else:
    tot = (fh) * (fhr)
print(fh, fhr)
print('Pay: ', tot)
```

### Código simplificado

```
try:
    hr=float(input('Horas de trabajo: '))
    phr=float(input('Precio por hr de trabajo: '))
except:
    print('Error, entre un numero valido')
    quit()

if hr>40:
    exfh=(hr-40)*(phr*0.5)
    prtot=(hr)*(phr)
    tot=exfh+prtot
else:
    tot=(hr)*(phr)

print(hr,phr)
print('Pay: ',tot)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ariel, estoy comenzando y agradezco el detalle de tu respuesta. Ahora si me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

pon tu input dentro del try

```
try:
    hr = input('Precio por hr de trabajo: ')
    fh=float(hr)
except:
    print('Error, entre un numero valido')
    quit()
```

Comment: Esto también funciona: `hr = float( input('Precio por hr de trabajo: ') )` y te ahorras la declaración de una segunda variable.

Comment: Y no es ese el problema